# FlatList not scrolling inside BottomSheetModal in React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Description:
I'm facing an issue with my React Native application, where I'm using a FlatList inside a BottomSheetModal to display a list of selectable items, but the FlatList scrolling is not working correctly.

```
<BottomSheetModalProvider>
      <Container>
        <Header title="Home" showDrawerButton />
        <View style={{ padding: 20, flex: 1 }}>
          <CardButton title="Nova venda" onPress={handleSaleModal} />
        </View>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        >
          <BottomSheetModal
            ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
            index={1}
            snapPoints={snapPoints}
            backgroundStyle={{
              borderRadius: 24,
              backgroundColor: COLORS.GRAY_700,
            }}
            handleIndicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: COLORS.BRAND_LIGHT }}
            backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
          >
            <ContainerBottomSheet>
              <Highlight title="Nova venda" subtitle="" />
              <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <CustomSelect
                  data={dataDropdownEmps}
                  onSelect={handleSelect}
                  showSearch
                />
              </View>
              <Button title="Iniciar" />
            </ContainerBottomSheet>
          </BottomSheetModal>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </Container>
    </BottomSheetModalProvider>
```

```
import { CaretDown, CaretUp } from "phosphor-react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  FlatList,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { useTheme } from "styled-components/native";
import { ButtonSelect, ButtonSelectText, Container } from "./styles";

interface CustomSelectProps {
  data: SelectItem[];
  onSelect: (item: SelectItem | null) => void;
  showSearch?: boolean;
}

interface SelectItem {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

export function CustomSelect({
  data,
  onSelect,
  showSearch = false,
}: CustomSelectProps) {
  const { COLORS } = useTheme();
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState<SelectItem | null>(null);
  const [isSearchClicked, setIsSearchClicked] = useState(false);

  const handleSelectItem = (item: SelectItem) => {
    setSelectedItem(item);
    onSelect(item);
    setIsSearchClicked(false);
  };

  const filteredData = data.filter((item) =>
    item.label.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
  );

  return (
    <Container>
      <ButtonSelect
        onPress={() => setIsSearchClicked(!isSearchClicked)}
        activeOpacity={0.7}
      >
        <ButtonSelectText>
          {selectedItem ? selectedItem.label : "Selecione um item"}
        </ButtonSelectText>
        {isSearchClicked ? (
          <CaretUp size={22} color={COLORS.WHITE} />
        ) : (
          <CaretDown size={22} color={COLORS.WHITE} />
        )}
      </ButtonSelect>
      {isSearchClicked && (
        <View
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            borderRadius: 6,
            marginTop: 10,
            gap: 10,
            backgroundColor: "white",
            elevation: 6,
          }}
        >
          {showSearch && (
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Search..."
              style={{
                width: "90%",
                height: 54,
                borderWidth: 0.5,
                borderColor: "#8e8e8e",
                borderRadius: 6,
                alignSelf: "center",
                marginTop: 10,
                paddingHorizontal: 10,
              }}
              value={search}
              onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
            />
          )}
          <FlatList
            data={filteredData}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => handleSelectItem(item)}
                style={[
                  {
                    width: "100%",
                    paddingHorizontal: 10,
                    height: 54,
                    borderBottomWidth: 0.2,
                    borderBottomColor: "#8e8e8e",
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                  },
                  // selectedItem?.value === item.value && styles.selectedItem,
                ]}
              >
                <Text>{item.label}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.value}
            contentContainerStyle={[{ paddingBottom: 40, maxHeight: 200 }]}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Problem:
The FlatList is rendering the list items correctly, but I can't scroll the list to see all items when there are more items than can fit on the screen. Scrolling simply doesn't work.

What I've Tried:

I've checked if the FlatList is wrapped in a component that's blocking scrolling, but I haven't found any issues.
I've tried setting the maximum height of the FlatList using maxHeight, but that also didn't solve the problem.
Could someone provide me with a hint on what might be causing this issue or how I can fix it?

Comment: What is the height of the `FlatList`? You can check this via "inspect". Could it be that the `FlatList` is overflowing